# Click automatically on button in browser

Tags: windows, mouse-click

I am as a user a website that has a export button and want to automatic click on the button  and save file in the my computer.I think about write JavaScript that click easy on the button but the page site has a authentication rule and i want to all these process should be automatically

1. Login
2. Go to the specific page
3. Click on Button
4. Save my in my PC

Is there any tools and application for do above operation?
Can I write any script for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) for browser automation.

Comment: can i set to click every 2 second?

Comment: Yes. You control the scripts - just add a timer function.